# Throttle a specific client (background job) in AzureSQL?

Tags: azure-sql-database, throttling

We have a background job that runs nightly (our timezone), but of course that is "middle of the day" somewhere else on the planet. This background job uses up all our available AzureSQL resources to run as fast as possible - and by doing so blocks our most important user-facing queries during that time.

Is there a way to throttle specific clients in AzureSQL? We have full control over the background job and can adjust its connection string or even the code if necessary. We want to run it only if there are no other queries at the moment. Optimally some kind of priorization value where we put our user-facing services at level 1000 and the background job at 10 or something like that.

Note: We cannot move the background job to a second replica of the database though, it has to run on the main database.

Comment: In SQL Azure MI you can use resource governor.  However, this is not exposed in normal SQL Azure.

Comment: Why is it blocking user-facing queries?  Is it doing DDL on tables?  Did you change the default READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT setting on the database?  Of do you mean that the queries are just slow?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: It's blocking user facing queries because the resource limit is reached (I guess it's called "DTUs" these times.)

Comment: Do you have any other databases you could consolidate with this one into an Elastic Pool with more DTUs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool

Comment: No, I only have this single database.

Comment: When the DTU limit is reached other queries should just slow down.  Perhaps so much that the client stops waiting and cancels the query, but they should still go through.  If you're seeing something different then you can investigate with the Query Store and/or Extended Events.  But you may need to adjust your code.  Without Resource Governor you could have the job perform small batches with breaks in-between either from the client or using WAITFOR DELAY.  Or you could try to optimize the code to require fewer resources.  Look first at the Query Store wait stats for the critical queries.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15#Waiting

Answer (score 2):

On SQL Server instances we have the option to use Resource Governor to limit resources (CPU, RAM) to specific workloads. [Resource Governor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/resource-governance-in-azure-sql-database/) is part of SQL Azure protection mechanisms, but is not available for us as a feature we can configure.

People is voting [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/11443791-dtu-resource-governor) for this feature to be available for us on SQL Azure.

You can use the [sys.dm_db_resource_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-resource-stats-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current) dynamic management view to identify when your Azure SQL database is not being used to start the background job. If you can divide the process on many parts that take 2-3 minutes of execution each one, and run each part in sequence and start each one when the database is idle, then this may be an option. You can run the same procedure and if the database is idle, it then may check on a status table the last part/step that ran successfully, and trigger execution of the next one.

Comment: I'm a little shocked that such a simple demand has a) only 12 votes and is b) not part of the database already : o

Comment: I have seen it since 2017. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d2d280ca-4c5d-4b78-be41-7edd7ff3d537/workload-group-resource-governor-in-azure?forum=ssdsgetstarted